# Run a bootable USB of command prompt compatible with multiboot

Tags: cmd, usb

I need to know if a program exists ( or if I can create) that runs that computer's command prompt from a USB, without having to log in.  I guess I don't really care if it is that computers cmd, but I need all of the modern functions of today's cmd.  I also need to make sure that it has full administrative privileges.  I know that it is possible, because just about every Linux system uses a similar system when it initially boots up, even when just downloaded to USB.

I guess I really need something that I can use with multiboot (a pure ISO file, not something like Rufus, which requires you to format usb).  I don't know, but I don't think an ms dos thingy would have all of today's commands in cmd.

Any help much appreciated.   Piece.

Edit:  I just need the equvolent of single user mode in a Mac.  Administrative access to the terminal without login info.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot windows to `safe mode` limited `command prompt`, or you can launch a cmd window via the `startup group` (but you can't get a full screen after XP and the window can be closed with the latter method).

That is the first issue for you to solve, and then you can consider booting from USB.